Cumulative distribution function of chi-squared distribution
I am trying to understand the proof here. At some point goes from
$$F_Y(y) = \frac{F_Y(y)}{\mathrm{d}y} \mathrm{d}y = f_Y(y) \mathrm{d}y \tag{1}$$
to
$$f_Y(y) \mathrm{d}y = \int_{V} \prod_{i=1}^{k}  \mathcal{N}(x_i; 0, 1) \mathrm{d}x_i \tag{2}$$
where $V$, the elemental shell volume at $y(x)$, which is proportional to the $(k−1)$-dimensional surface in $k$-space for which
$$y = \sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i^2 \tag{3}$$
is fulfilled. From the definition of cumulative distribution function (CDF) we have
$$F_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{y} f_Y(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \tag{4}$$
Can you please someone explain a little more the definition of $V$, i.e. what is that $y(x)$ and why it is proportional to the $(k−1)$-dimensional surface in $k$-space for which (3) is fulfilled?  Then, how we go from the basic definition of CDF in (3) to (2)? Any help is highly appreciated.

Eq. (1) is total nonsense. Don't read such crap. $f_Y$ is the derivative of $F_Y,.$ That is it. Even if that author just made a typo it is frustrating to see it published. Better $$dF_Y(y) = \frac{dF_Y(y)}{\mathrm{d}y} \mathrm{d}y = f_Y(y) \mathrm{d}y,.$$

@KurtG. thanks for the comment. What does $dF_{Y}(y)$ means? I understand it as $dF_{Y}(y) = F_{Y}'(y) = \frac{dF_Y(y)}{\mathrm{d}y}$. Can you elaborate a little more?

I won't elaborate on that (asking what stand-alone differentials mean is one of the most annoying questions on MSE). Hint: $dF=f,dy$ means $$\frac{dF}{dy}=f,.$$ That is it!

@KurtG. Can you please answer my questions in the post?

This boils down to repeating the proof in the link you are reading thereby fixing the author's minor typo we found three days ago and probably calling $V$ the sphere with radius $\sqrt{y(x)}$ instead of "elemental shell." That's all. That proof seems not that bad.

@KurtG. thanks for the comment! I think I get it now but wouldn't be better to write
$$dF_Y(y) = f_Y(y) = \int_{V} \prod_{i=1}^{k}  \mathcal{N}(x_i; 0, 1) \mathrm{d}x_i $$
instead of (2) according to the definition of densities associated with multiple variables here?

You go from one nonsense $dF=\frac F{dy}$ to another nonsense $dF=f,.$ The correct way of writing this I posted two times above.

The cumulative distribution of a Chi square distribution of order $N$ is   is explicit only if $N=2n$ is even, thanks to the formula
$$\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t}\frac{t^n}{n!}dt=\sum_{k=0}^ne^{-x}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$ that you can check by taking derivative of both sides.

Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate a little more on this and how it is connected with the integral on $V$?
